# Momentum measurement of a particle in an infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

After measuring a quantum state for a particular measurable, the state collapses to one of the eigenstate of that measurable. If we measure for momentum in an infinite square well, the system will collapse to a momentum eigenstate. But uncertainty in position is not arbitrary large (it's $2L$). So we are left with finite uncertainty in momentum and position at the same time. Does this mean that we aren't supposed to make such measurement? Or something else.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287040/2451